# Between friend and acquaintance?

Tags: pronouns

What do I call people in between friends and acquaintance? I want to refer to my classmates who I know somewhat well and are friendly with, but not friends.

Comment: how about [colleague?](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/colleague)

Comment: [_Acquaintance_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/acquaintance) is the usual word for “a relationship less intimate than friendship”; what's unsatisfactory about that word?

Comment: @Lumberjack That would be a good one for co-workers but may sound out of place for classmates (unless there's a close working relationship, e.g. in grad school).

Comment: **"Classmates"** says it clearly, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use "classmates." Often when we want to refer to classmates with whom we are friends, we say something like "my friends from school." So if you say "classmates," it suggests they are only classmates and not really friends.

I don't think there really is a commonly used word that specifically means a relationship between friend and acquaintance. I think in standard English those are your two basic choices. You can always qualify, saying things like "good friend," "close friend," "casual friend," or "bare acquaintance." It really depends on the situation and the precise nuance you are trying to convey.